# How to spot un-weighted vertices?

Tags: vertices, weight-painting, unity, vertex-weights

[image]

As you can I see have three rouge vertices that are not a part of a vertex group and/or doesn't have weights on them.

[image]

Is there an easy way to spot them without going through each bone?

More clearly: How to spot unassigned vertices in weight paint mode?

Comment: Select all the pose bones and move them.  The three unassigned "rogue" verts will reveal themselves.

Comment: Vertex Mode > Header 'Select' menu > 'Select by Trait' > 'Select Ungrouped Verts' might be helpful, but it will select 0-weight verts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the options in the armature modifier: *"Display modifier in edit mode"* and *"Adjust edit cage to the modifier result"*.

[image]

In complement, concerned bones are generally the one used for nearly connected vertices, you can see them in the properties panel:

[image]